Integral closure of ring A is integral closed?
Let $A,B$ be ring and $A \subseteq  B$. Let $C$ be integral closure of $A$ in $B$.
Then $C$ is integral closed, isn't it?
Let D be integral closure of C. $D \supseteq  C$ is clear. Let $x \in D$, then $x$ is integral over $C$. I want to prove that $x$ is integral over $A$. How can I prove this.

If you take $A=B$, then $A$ is trivially integrally closed in $B$ but $A$ itself need not be integrally closed.

@user6 I know that "integrally closed" is used when $A$ is a UFD, but here this is not the case. I think the op wants to show that $C$ is integrally closed in $B$. In your example, $A$ is integrally closed in $A$, so your counterexample doesn't work I think.

See Integral dependence over rings is transitive. This is a well-known result that you can find in most of algebra books. See for instance the 5th chapter of Atiyah-Macdonald's book "Introduction to commutative algebra".

the standard convention is: a domain $D$ is called integrally closed if it is integrally closed in its field of fractions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain

I know the convention, I'm just saying that the op does not recquire $A$ to be a domain.

The trick is to use a slightly different description of "integral closedness". You wish to show that $x$ is integral over $A$, i.e. that there is a relation of the form:
$$x^n = \sum_i a_i x^i$$
with the $a_i$'s in $A$. Notice the following: this relation exists if and only if the $A$-module $A[x]$ is of finite type (the proof is quite easy).
So far, we only know that the $C$-module $C[x]$ is finitely generated. So there is a relation
$$x^n = \sum_i c_i x^i$$
with the $c_i$'s in $C$. Let $A'=A[c_0,...,c_{n-1}]$, we obviously have $A'[x]$ finitely generated, so $x$ is integral over $A'$. Moreover, $A'$ is a finitely generated $A$-module (by definition of $C$). This shows that $A[x,c_1,...,c_{n-1}]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, but we cannot a priori conclude that so is $A[x]$. Luckily, there is an additional, more involved, equivalent characterization of integral closedness (see wikipedia, or really any commutative algebra textbook):

$x \in D$ is integral over $A$ if and only if there exists a finitely generated $A$-module $M \subseteq D$ which contains $A[x]$.

Taking this for granted, we are done: $M=A'[x]$ works. Implication $\implies$ is easy: take $M=A[x]$ itself. For the converse, we need the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem for modules. I will let you look up the details for yourself, but here is the general idea. Consider the endomorphism $u$ of $M$ given by multiplication by $x$ ; because $M$ is finitely generated by $m$ elements, the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem gives $a_i$'s in $A$ such that the endomorphism
$$u^m - \sum_i a_i u^i$$
is zero. Now evaluate it at $1 \in A \subseteq M$, you find the relation for $x$ you were looking for.
This result makes sense: if "multiplication by $x$" satisfies some relation over $A$ on a big module $M$, it still satisfies it on any smaller submodule stable under that multiplication (which is the case for $A[x]$).
